# Telegram comment post as channel

Tags: telegram, sender, pyrogram

Some comments in telegram discussions are sent from channels (click to name and visit channel page). This messages has `sender_chat` property.
How can I post comments as channel? (manually or via pyrogram).
P.S. I can select sender if comment is in my channel, but other chats does'nt have sender switcher btn.
Sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 1):

Specify [`set_send_as_chat()`](https://docs.pyrogram.org/api/methods/set_send_as_chat) before invoking `send_message()` like below (Pyrogram 2.0+):

```py
from pyrogram import Client

Credentials = Client(
    name="ad_comment_on_channel",
    api_id=---,
    api_hash="---",
    device_model="Ad Comment On Channel",
    app_version="ACoCh v1.0",
)

with Credentials as app:
    # Discussion Group's Numeric ID (starting with -100) [integer]
    group_ID = -1001234567890
    # ID of a post in the discussion group [integer]
    msg_ID = 123

    # Select your public channel for anonymous commenting
    app.set_send_as_chat(group_ID, "YourPublicChannelUserName")

    app.send_message(
        chat_id=group_ID,
        reply_to_message_id=msg_ID,
        text="My Comment"
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Ali Abdi for helping!
Additional details - you must be **channel owner** to post messages as channel (admins can't do that)